# How to filter efficiently with optional params in Kotlin?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, filter, mapping

I am working on `Kotlin` list `filter`. Let's say I have a list of `Worker` instances and I want to design a function which filters the list on condition for `startAge` and `maxSalary` **nullable** params.

#### Data class

```
data class Worker(name:String?, age: Int?, salary: Int?){

}
```

#### Function filteredList()

```
fun filterList(original: List<Worker>, startAge: Int?, maxSalary: Int?): List<Student>{
    val list = original.filter{
        it.age >= startAge && it.salary <= maxSalary
    }
    return list
}
```

At that point, I want to design the `filterList` function in such a way if any param is passed as a `null`, that condition should not be skipped. How do I do that? For example, calling with

`val list = filterList(original, null, 100)` should return list of workers whose max salary is `100` but does not matter the age.

#### My thought

In this particular problem I can choose default `startAge = Int.MAX_VALUE` and `maxSalary = Int.MIN_VALUE` when `null` is passed in params. But I think there can be many kind of conditional check inside filter (i.e compare dates, string equality check, evaluate expressions etc.) which might not always be possible to cover with `default` value. How can I get rid of this glitch?

Comment: In your case you should check with either of values instead of both of them in **&& condition**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a helper function `isNullOr` to check for `null` or invoke a predicate otherwise:

```
inline infix fun <T> T?.isNullOr(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean = if (this != null) predicate(this) else true
```

With this function your filter statement will look like this:

```
fun filterList(original: List<Worker>, startAge: Int?, maxSalary: Int?): List<Worker> {
    val list = original.filter { worker ->
        startAge isNullOr { worker.age >= it } && maxSalary isNullOr { worker.salary <= it }
    }
    return list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Elvis operator `?:` to evaluate the age or the salary to a ridiculous value (`Int.MIN_VALUE` or `Int.MAX_VALUE`) if the parameter is null.

```
it.age >= (startAge ?: Int.MIN_VALUE) && it.salary <= (maxSalary ?: Int.MAX_VALUE)
```

If say `startAge` is null, then `it.age` will be compared to `Int.MIN_VALUE`, which will always be true. Same goes for `maxSalary`.

But you also should decide what happens when `it.age` or `it.salary` is null, which you did not mention in the question.

Edit:

If you don't have default values, you can use `?.let` to transform the optional params to optional booleans, then use `?:` to default them to `true`:

```
fun filterList(original: List<Worker>, startAge: Int?, maxSalary: Int?): List<Worker>{
    val list = original.filter{
        (startAge?.let { x -> it.age >= x } ?: true) && (maxSalary?.let { x -> it.salary <= x } ?: true)
    }
    return list
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My posted example was not perfect to catch the glitch. Please see the Updated post.

Comment: If the condition does not depends on `<=` or `>=`operators. How can I skip some of the conditions which depends on null params and still cover others?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Although this could be done in a general way, I would still recommend you to handle this on a case by case basis. What is your actual case?

Comment: In my real cases there are string params which needs to be compared for equality check as well as there are date type params where I cannot choose such kind of default value. Default value works only for `<=` or `>=` operation on primitive numbers type.

Comment: thats much cleaner now.